# User input must equal

Tags: batch-file, input, set

How do I only accept the following values with user input?

i.e.

```
SET /P POSID=Enter POS Number: 

SET test=1%POSID%
IF %test% EQU 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 (11-15) 21, 22, 23, 24,25 (21-25) GOTO POSIDGOOD
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%a in (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21, 22, 23, 24,25) do if "%posid%"=="%%a" GOTO POSIDGOOD
echo bad posid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal

for %%a in (11 12 13 14 15  21 22 23 24 25) do set valid[%%a]=true

SET /P POSID=Enter POS Number: 

if defined valid[%POSID%] GOTO POSIDGOOD
echo bad posid
```

You may use the same variables of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413586/will-this-fail-or-better-way-of-scripting/22414911#22414911):

```
if defined posNum[%POSID%] GOTO POSIDGOOD
```